# O que é IHTMLDocument2?

Tags: c#, html, html5

Quando é utilizado, como é utilizado, não encontrei nada que explique isso para mim?

Exemplo de código:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate(new Uri(location, UriKind.Absolute));
IHTMLDocument2 myDoc = new HTMLDocumentClass();
myDoc.write(new object[] { wb.DocumentText});
myDoc.close();
```

Comment: Isso? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752574(v%3Dvs.85) Viu que é algo obsoleto?

Comment: o número é só a versão da interface, é mantido assim por uma questão de compatibilidade